# Why does my PHP script work in IE 9 but not IE 8 or Chrome 24?

Tags: php, cross-browser

I'm not a developer, so I'm coming to you all for help. I've searched Google for an answer, but most of what I'm seeing says since PHP runs on the server, the end-user's browser doesn't matter. However, I'm troubleshooting an issue and I just learned that, although I can reproduce the issue in Chrome 24 and IE 8, everything works perfectly in IE 9. It would be nice to have more information about whether certain elements in a PHP script can affect whether or not a specific browser can handle it.

The following is the pre-configured script I got with Adobe Captivate. I've only made one modification so far, which I've marked with a comment. Basically, Captivate generates a flash file that I'm publishing on a web server. When the user views the presentation in a web browser, it opens a form at the end. When they click submit, the swf sends information it's stored to this script (I provide the URL in the project file) so it can parse and store the data.

```
<?php # InternalServerReporting.php
# Copyright 2000-2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.
#
   print "<pre>\n";

#
   foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) 
   {
      if($k == "CompanyName")
      {
        $CompanyName = $v;
      }
      if($k == "DepartmentName")
      {
        $DepartmentName = $v;
      }
      if($k == "CourseName")
      {
        $CourseName = $v;
      }
      if($k == "Filename")
      {
        $Filename = $v;
      }
      if($k == "Filedata")
      {
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $Filedata = stripslashes($v);
        else
        $Filedata = $v;
      }
   }

    $ResultFolder = "./"."CaptivateResults";
    mkdir($ResultFolder, 0777); #I inserted the 0777 to solve a permissions issue.
    $CompanyFolder = $ResultFolder."//".$CompanyName;
    mkdir($CompanyFolder);
    $DepartmentFolder = $CompanyFolder."//".$DepartmentName;
    mkdir($DepartmentFolder);
    $CourseFolder = $DepartmentFolder."//".$CourseName;
    mkdir($CourseFolder);
    $FilePath = $CourseFolder."//".$Filename;
    $Handle = fopen($FilePath, 'w');
    fwrite($Handle, $Filedata);
    fclose($Handle);


   print "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `$_POST` array is the same when sent by both IE9 and Chrome?

Comment: It must be something in the swf file. I dont know what is not working (its not in your post), but the problem is not in your php script if it is working on other browsers. Must be something with the swf.

Comment: lovely code. you're allowing malicious users to completely specify a filename/filepath so they can scribble a file **ANYWHERE** on your server. if this code was automatically generated, I suggest you send Adobe a nastygram in the form of a very large flaming sack of poo.

Comment: @slugonamission, is there a way to test that easily? Layman here. :)

Comment: it's also worth pointing out that this code is using PHP features like magic quotes that have been deprecated and removed from recent versions of PHP because they're so insecure. This is dangerous code.

Comment: @MarcB, I didn't think of that (obviously), but it makes sense. Is there a way to make this more secure? If it's something intensive, it's yet another mark against using this solution. Thanks.

Comment: @SDC I never quite understood this one, if theres no connection to a database, is there a point in securing it?

Comment: @user2018905 `die(var_dump($_POST))`

Comment: @slugonamission, do I just put that at the end of the script? What does it do?